# Rails - Restricting results in has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have 3 models, User, Dealer and Role, which look as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles
  has_many :sales, :through => :roles
  has_many :appraisals, :through => :roles
  has_many :dealers, :through => :roles
end

class Dealer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles, :as => :role_originator
  has_many :users, :through => :roles
end

class Sale < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles, :as => :role_originator
  has_many :users, :through => :roles
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :role_type
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :role_originator, :polymorphic => true
end
```

The associations are working as expected - for example, I can do `dealer.users` and get all of the users who have roles at that dealer.

The problem I have is that I would like to be able to do `dealer.users.first.roles` and return only the roles that are associated with that dealer, but at present it returns all of the roles that are associated with the user, regardless of whether they refer to another dealer.

How can I modify my models to allow `dealer.users.first.roles` to return only the roles that are associated with the selected dealer and user, and not all of the roles for the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your query is that you're finding the first user of a dealer then asking for that user's roles, which has nothing to do with the dealer.

If you already know what dealer you want, and you want the first user from that dealer, then you can do something like

```
@dealer = dealer
@user = @dealer.users.first
@roles = Role.where("user_id = ? AND dealer_id = ?", @user.id, @dealer.id)
```

This should return only the roles shared by that user and that dealer.